# Use component's value in template

Tags: angular, angular8

I have the following Tab component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tab',
  templateUrl: './tab.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tab.component.css'],
  providers: [TabService]
})

export class TabComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() active: boolean;
  @Input() title: string;

  public value: string = 'Testing';

  constructor(private tabService: TabService) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

}
```

With the following template:

```
<div [hidden]="!active" class="toolbar">
  <ng-content select="[toolbar]"></ng-content>
</div>
<div [hidden]="!active" class="content">
  <ng-content></ng-content>  
</div>
```

I used it as follows:

```
<tabs>
  <tab title="Tab 1">
    Value: {{value}}
  </tab>
</tabs>
```

However `{{value}}` shows no value ... How to display it when using tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the 'Testing' string, include it in the tab template:

```
<div [hidden]="!active" class="toolbar">
  <ng-content select="[toolbar]"></ng-content>
</div>
{{ value }}
<div [hidden]="!active" class="content">
  <ng-content></ng-content>  
</div>
```

In your tab component, active isn't given a value and thus it's falsy, so it's hidden. Set it to true:

```
<tabs>
  <tab title="Tab 1" [active]="true">
    Value: {{value}}
  </tab>
</tabs>
```

Also, `value` is transcluded so its value comes from the component that has the tab component in its template. So you need to set it from the parent template.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mhy75c)

Answer (score 2):

Your `value` property is in the TabComponent, but you are trying to use it in a template of another component. You should move `Value: {{value}}` into the TabComponent template, or create a property called `value` in the component where `<tab>` is being used.